# how to place icon button wherever and as i like in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I want to make a toolbar in my app where the icons are placed in the top right and i want to place them as i like .

I want to make them small and i have a little bit of spacing between them at the top right , and the top left will be the logo.

Thanks a lot

I tried this code but it's for bottom toolbar :

```
MDBoxLayout:
            size_hint_y:None
            md_bg_color:.9,.9,.9,1
            height:dp(60)
            padding:[0,0,0,15]
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation:'vertical'
                MDIconButton:
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
                    icon:'home'
                    theme_text_color:'Custom'
                    text_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color
                MDLabel:
                    text:'Home'
                    valign:"center"
                    theme_text_color:'Custom'
                    text_color:app.theme_cls.primary_color
                    halign:"center"
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation:'vertical'
                MDIconButton:
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
                    icon:'bell'
                MDLabel:
                    text:'Notification'
                    valign:"center"
                    halign:"center"
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation:'vertical'
                MDIconButton:
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
                    icon:'cards-heart'
                MDLabel:
                    text:'Favorite'
                    valign:"center"
                    halign:"center"
            MDBoxLayout:
                orientation:'vertical'
                MDIconButton:
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5}
                    icon:'account'
                MDLabel:
                    text:'Profile'
                    valign:"center"
                    halign:"center"
```

but didn't work for me , i guess i did something wrong in syntax .

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).